# query relation based on parent column

Tags: php, laravel

i have 2 tables

```
accounts  : id , title , disabled , transaction_amount_limit , transaction_count_limit 

account_limits : id , account_id , transaction_amount , transaction_count , date
```

so each account has bunch of transaction each day ... i want to select the a account that hasn't reached its transactions limit .... current transaction for each account is stored in account_limits table

basically i want to say select account that doesn't have `account_limits` row or have `account_limits` but hasn't reached the limits `account_limits.transaction_amount < accounts.transaction_amount_limit` && `account_limits.transaction_count < accounts.transaction_count_limit`

something like

```
select * from `accounts`

(  where not exists (select * from `account_limits` where `accounts`.`id` = `account_limits`.`account_id`)
OR 
where exists (select * from `account_limits` where `accounts`.`id` = `account_limits`.`account_id` &&  account_limits.transaction_amount < accounts.transaction_amount_limit  && account_limits.transaction_count < accounts.transaction_count_limit)
)
```

i have this so far

```
    $account = Account::where('disabled' , 0 )->where(function($q){
        $q->whereDoesntHave('AccountLimit')->orWhere('....') ;
    })->get();
```

as @Flame suggested i tried

```
Account::whereHas('accountLimits', function($query) {
    $query->where('account_limits.transaction_amount', '<', 'accounts.transaction_amount_limit')
    ->where('account_limits.transaction_count', '<', 'accounts.transaction_count_limit');
})->orHas('accountLimits', '=', 0);
```

the problem is for some reason

```
where('account_limits.transaction_amount', '<', 'accounts.transaction_amount_limit')
```

in the output will translate to

```
where `account_limits`.`transaction_amount`  < 'accounts.transaction_amount_limit'
```

and query fails , there's problem with quotations

```
    this 

 'accounts.transaction_amount_limit' 

should be

 `accounts`.`transaction_amount_limit`
```

Comment: From my reading of your question, it seems the `limit` values are in the `accounts` database and the actual values are in the `account_limits` database? Is that right?

Comment: @Nick yes , `account_limits` contains current transaction stats (amount , count ) basically after each transaction i update `account_limits ` and add the new transaction amount to the table

Comment: I'm not a laravel expert but could give you a straight MySQL query if that would help...

Comment: @Nick i've added the query to the answer pleas ignore syntax errors

Comment: @hretic just don't use the table name, just the column instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example answer in the Eloquent syntax. Note that you need to add the relation:

```
// Account.php , your eloquent model
public function accountLimits()
{
    return $this->hasMany(AccountLimit::class);
}
```

And for the query:

```
Account::whereHas('accountLimits', function($query) {
    $query->where('account_limits.transaction_amount', '<', 'accounts.transaction_amount_limit')
    ->where('account_limits.transaction_count', '<', 'accounts.transaction_count_limit');
})->orHas('accountLimits', '=', 0);
```

This checks for your where-clause in the relation using `whereHas`, and if it is not a match, it will also add the records that match in the `orHas`, which finds all Accounts without accountLimits relationships.

Comment: is there a difference between `AccountLimit::class` and `App\AccountLimit` in the model when defining the relation ?

Comment: your way is almost works , pleas check my question bottom i've added additional info

Comment: The definition it is exactly the same, but the string definition does not have code assist on my IDE, so I always use `Model::class`. It returns a string as well so in essence it is the same.

Comment: thanx , i used whereRaw to handle quotations problem

Answer (score 0):

As a straight MySQL query, something like this should work:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM accounts a
JOIN limits l ON l.transaction_amount < a.transaction_amount_limit AND 
                 l.transaction_count  < a.transaction_count_limit
```

The `JOIN` condition will filter out any accounts that have met or exceeded either their `transaction_amount` or `transaction_count` limits.

Comment: thanx im looking for ORM syntax , if not found this would be plan B

Comment: @hretic I know. Hopefully you will get a laravel expert who will show you how to implement this query in laravel.

Answer (score 0):

It is good idea for me to keep transaction_count and transaction_limit in same table (accounts). 
Then you can compare this columns.

$accounts = Account::whereRaw("transaction_count  <  transaction_limit)->get();